# Windows: ffmpeg drawtext with mp3 metadata

Tags: windows, ffmpeg, mp3, metadata

Trying to make ffmpeg create image/video with data from mp3/id3 (pref. id3v2) tags, for ex:

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i "color=c=white:s=720x480" -i "01 - Steel Guitar Rag.mp3" -shortest -filter_complex "drawtext=expansion=normal:fontfile=usb.ttf:fontcolor=black:x=10:y=10:fontsize=10:text='Artist\: %{metadata\:artist}'" "01 - Steel Guitar Rag.png"
```

*SHOULD* print:

> Artist: Bob Wills And His Texas Playboys

but I just can't seem to get the keys/escaping of the string right for it to work I get typically either "Artist: " or "artist}" printed depending on where/how-many \'s I use...

How do I need to format the `text=''` to actually work right?

Comment: I'm trying to print the artist/etc from the mp3's id3 tags, ffmpeg's documentation really sucks for describing how to actually use drawtext with "%{metadata:<key>}" nor does it even hint at what any VALID keys might be... and I'd rather not do the text statically for each file as i will eventually be doing hundreds (making videos for an old man with poor vision to play on his 40inch TV so he'll be able to listen to the music and still read the artist/title/album info, unlike on an IPod or CD Jewel-case without a magnifying glass)

Answer (score 0):

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i "color=c=white:s=720x480" -i "01 - Steel Guitar Rag.mp3" -shortest -filter_complex "drawtext=expansion=normal:fontfile=usb.ttf:fontcolor=black:x=10:y=10:fontsize=10:text=\'Artist\: %{metadata:artist}\'" -vframes 1 "01 - Steel Guitar Rag.png"
```

I also added -vframes 1 to prevent the production of multiple images

Comment: still doesn't print the actual artist just "Artist: ", plus i was only using PNG as it was quicker than encoding an entire mp4 each time I'm testing and ultimately "-vframes 1" would likely be a bad idea for producing video

Comment: yeah drawtext only shows frame metadata which is unlikely to have an 'artist' tag

Answer (score 0):

This will probably require scripting. You can use your favorite tagging tool to get the artist metadata, then use that in as a variable in your `ffmpeg` command.

Example using `ffprobe` to get artist metadata:

```
ffprobe -v error -select_streams a:0 -show_entries tags=artist -of default=nw=1:nk=1 input.mp3
Bob Wills And His Texas Playboys
```

(Un)fortunately I don't know how to script anything in Windows, but here is a simple Bash solution if anyone else is interested in doing the same:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Usage: ./drawmeta input.mp3
# Will output a PNG with same basename as the input file.

artistname=$(ffprobe -v error -select_streams a:0 -show_entries tags=artist -of default=nw=1:nk=1 "$1")

ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i "color=c=white:s=720x480" -i "$1" -filter_complex "drawtext=fontfile=/path/to/font.ttf:fontcolor=black:x=10:y=10:fontsize=10:text='Artist\: $artistname'" -frames:v 1 "${1%.*}.png"
```